# Modify list elements if last two entries are equal

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Suppose I have a list as follows

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}}
```

and I want to check the last two coordinates are equal or not. If that is the case then I want it to print out T after that list. So the result should be

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1,T}}
```

I am thinking about using "if" but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Try: `(Append[#, If[#[[-1]] == #[[2]], "T", Nothing]]) & /@ {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}}`

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most expressive would be to use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}};
Replace[
  list, 
  {rest___, l_, l_} :> {rest, l, l, T},
  1
]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}} *)
```

Some alternatives:

```
Replace[list, list : {___, l_, l_} :> Append[list, T], 1]
Replace[list, l_ /; Equal @@ l[[-2 ;;]] :> Append[l, T], 1]
Replace[list, {list : PatternSequence[___, l_, l_]} :> {list, T}, 1]
Map[If[Equal @@ #[[-2 ;;]], Append[#, T], #] &, list]
Map[If[#[[-2]] == #[[-1]], Append[#, T], #] &, list]
Map[If[Equal @@ #[[-2 ;;]], Append[T], # &]@# &, list]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alist = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}}

Join @@@ Transpose[{#, 
      List /@ Equal @@@ #[[All, -2 ;; -1]]}] /. {False -> Nothing, 
    True -> T} & @alist
```

---

A simpler version of the above:

```
# ~ Join ~ If[Equal @@ #[[-2 ;; -1]], {T}, {Nothing}] & /@ alist
```

**Description**: Take a sublist (`#`) and `Join` an item with it. The item will be `T` if the last two entries are `Equal`, else `Nothing`. `Map (/@)` this over the entire list.

---

Result:

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
A = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}};
```

---

Another way:

```
 Map[If[Mean[#[[-2 ;; -1]]] === #[[-1]], Append[#, T], #] &, A]
```

> `{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3) and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {a : {__, x_, x_}} :> {Splice @ a, T}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}

Using function deconstruction

```
f[a:{__, x_, x_}] := {Splice @ a, T}

f[a_] := a

f /@ list
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}

Answer (score 2):

If your data is always a list of lists and you always want the transformation performed at that second level, then this works (I've named your data `theData`):

```
Replace[theData, {head___, t_, t_} :> {head, t, t, "T"}, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1}};
```

---

Another way using `Take`:

```
If[Equal @@ Take[#, -2], Append[#, T], #] & /@ list
```

> `{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}`

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. s : {__, a_, b_} /; Equal @@ {a, b} :> Append[T]@s
```

> `{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, T}}`